# Recursively changing values of a nested dataclass in python

Tags: python, recursion, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass like this:

```py
class chapter:
    title: str
    text: str = ''
    chapter: List['chapter'] = field(default_factory=list)
    removed: bool = False
```

Say there is a list object that contains instances of that dataclass with these values:

```py
content = [
    chapter(
        'chapter 1',
        chapter=[
            chapter('subchapter 1', "Lorem ipsum dolor"),
            chapter('subchapter 2', "Nullam a ligula")
        ]
    ),
    chapter(
        'chapter 2',
        chapter=[
            chapter('subchapter 1', "Fusce eget commodo augue"),
            chapter('subchapter 2', "Pellentesque pretium")
        ]
    ),
    chapter(
        'chapter 3', removed=True
    ),
    chapter(
        'chapter 3',
        chapter=[
            chapter('subchapter 1', "Duis sit amet tempus lectus"),
        ]
    ),
]
```

Let's say I want to recursively set values `removed` to True for a selected chapter with an index 0, and in all subchapters of the chapter. How can I do that? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The naming in your code is a bit confusing - you should name the class `Chapter` instead of `chapter` and the list `chapter` should probably be called `chapters`.

Having said that, this appears to be what you want:

```
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class Chapter:
    title: str
    text: str = ''
    chapters: List['Chapter'] = field(default_factory=list)
    removed: bool = False

    def remove(self):
        self.removed = True
        for chapter in self.chapters:
            chapter.remove()


content = [
    Chapter(
        title='chapter 1',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Lorem ipsum dolor"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Nullam a ligula")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 2',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Fusce eget commodo augue"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Pellentesque pretium")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3', removed=True
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Duis sit amet tempus lectus"),
        ]
    ),
]


content[0].remove()
print(content)
```

Calling `.remove()` on a chapter sets `.removed` to `True`, but also calls `.remove()` on any of its subchapters, recursively setting `.removed` on all of them and their subchapters.

Comment: subchapter can contain subsubchapter

Comment: @funnydman and if you run the code, you'll find that those are removed as well, as the `.remove()` method is called on them.

Comment: Implementation on the databases level looks good

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I messed with naming conventions. Thought it was not really a class, but a dataclass

Comment: @Sonotoki everything in python is an class (object) in one way or another, just FYI.

Comment: @Sonotoki a "dataclass" isn't really a thing, unless it means "a class generated by the `dataclasses.dataclass` class factory/code generator"

Comment: @HampusLarsson well, everything is *an instance of a class*, not everything is a class.

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive function:

```
def remove_recursive(chapter_instance: chapter) -> None:
    chapter_instance.removed = True
    for c in chapter_instance.chapter:
        remove_recursive(c)
```

Note that conventionally you would call your class `Chapter`, and then could use the name `chapter` to refer to an instance of that class (instead of `chapter_instance` as I've very awkwardly done here.)

Comment: Oh, thank you! Sorry, I'm still learning about dataclasses

Comment: A dataclass is just a particular type of class -- all the usual conventions for defining a class apply to defining a dataclass (except that there are some methods, like `__init__`, that get defined for you automatically by the `@dataclass` decorator).