# Recursively finding an object in a nested dataclass and edit the found object

Tags: python, recursion, python-dataclasses

This is a question related to my previous [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74061708/recursively-changing-values-of-a-nested-dataclass-in-python).
Thank you all who helped me to figure out how to recursively remove chapters!

### Some backstory

I'm writing a telegram bot in which you can create pdfs out of telegram posts (a post may contain a maximum of 4096 characters). A very specific task indeed. In telegram bots, you only have inline buttons that contain a **button name** and an **id**. The bot lists chapters as inline buttons. As for subchapters, you'd continuously click until you reach to that specific chapter you wanted to access.

For example, I want to add a chapter in `chapter 1 -> subchapter 2` with name of **"subsubchapter 1"**:

1. Click to `chapter 1`
2. Bot re-renders buttons, listing subchapters in **chapter 1**, then click `subchapter 2`
3. There you add your chapter

Below is my draft that I come up with with my trial and errors for this problem:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Chapter:
    title: str
    text: str = ''
    removed: bool = False
    chapters: List['Chapter'] = field(default_factory=list)

    def add_chapter(self, title: str, where: List[str] = []):
        '''the where is a path to a chapter'''
        if not where:
            # check the occurrences of a chapter
            for chapter in self.chapters:
                if chapter.title == title:
                    return False

            self.chapters.append(Chapter(title))
            return True

        # recursively reach to a selected chapter
        for chapter in self.chapters:
            for x in where:
                if chapter.title == x:
                    if len(where) == 1:
                        # check the occurrences of a chapter
                        for _ in chapter.chapters:
                            if _.title == title:
                                return False
                        # my small brain couldn't function at all here
                        chapter.chapters.append(Chapter(title))
                        return True
                    else:
                        self.add_chapter(where[1:])

    def remove(self):
        self.removed = True
        for chapter in self.chapters:
            chapter.remove()


class Content:
    '''A mini database handler'''

    def __init__(self, content: List[Chapter]) -> None:
        self.content = content

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        i = 0
        for x in self.content:
            if not x.removed:
                i += 1
        return i

    def add_chapter_name(self, title: str, where: List[str] = None):
        if where:
            for chapter in self.content:
                if chapter.title == where[0] and not chapter.removed:
                    return chapter.add_chapter(title, where[1:])

        for x in self.content:
            if x.title == title and not x.removed:
                return False

        self.content.append(Chapter(title))
        return True

    # there is more


content = Content([
    Chapter(
        title='chapter 1',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Lorem ipsum dolor"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Nullam a ligula")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 2',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Fusce eget commodo augue"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Pellentesque pretium")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3', removed=True
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Duis sit amet tempus lectus"),
        ]
    ),
])

content.content[0].remove()

content.add_chapter_name('chapter 1')
content.add_chapter_name('subchapter 1', ['chapter 1'])
if not content.add_chapter_name('subchapter 1', ['chapter 1']):
    print("you can't")
content.add_chapter_name('subsubchapter 1', ['chapter 1', 'subchapter 1'])

# this will not insert the chapter to the expected place
content.add_chapter_name(
    'subsubsubchapter 1',
    ['chapter 1', 'subchapter 1', 'subsubsubchapter 1']
)
```

Again, any suggestions are appreciated. Just a suggestion should be enough, really. I don't want to take too much of your time.

Comment: Holy! All I need was just patience ;') I figured it out. For reference: https://realpython.com/python-recursion/

Answer (score 0):

It's just a prototype, but the method works as expected.

```py
from typing import List

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Chapter:
    title: str
    text: str = ''
    removed: bool = False
    chapters: List['Chapter'] = field(default_factory=list)


content: List[Chapter] = [
    Chapter(
        title='chapter 1',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Lorem ipsum dolor"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Nullam a ligula")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 2',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Fusce eget commodo augue"),
            Chapter('subchapter 2', "Pellentesque pretium")
        ]
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3', removed=True
    ),
    Chapter(
        'chapter 3',
        chapters=[
            Chapter('subchapter 1', "Duis sit amet tempus lectus"),
        ]
    ),
]


def add_chapter(content: List[Chapter], title: str, where: List[str] = None):
    if where is None:
        content.append(Chapter(title))
        return True
    if len(where) != 0:
        if isinstance(content, list):
            x = content
        else:
            x = content.chapters
        for chapter in x:
            if chapter.title == where[0]:
                for _ in chapter.chapters:
                    if _.title == title:
                        return False
                if len(where) != 1:
                    add_chapter(chapter, title, where[1:])
                else:
                    chapter.chapters.append(Chapter(title))
                    return True
    else:
        return


add_chapter(content, 'chapter 4')
add_chapter(content, 'subchapter 1', ['chapter 4'])
if not add_chapter(content, 'subchapter 1', ['chapter 4']):
    print("you can't")
add_chapter(content, 'subsubchapter 1', ['chapter 4', 'subchapter 1'])

# this will not insert the chapter to the expected place
# edit: now it works
add_chapter(
    content,
    'subsubsubchapter 1',
    ['chapter 4', 'subchapter 1', 'subsubchapter 1']
)
```